# How to calculate slots in a day in a java?

Tags: java

I have a three fields

1. Day's  start time ( say 8:00:00) (this is java.util.date)
2. Days end time (say 22:00:00) (java.util.date)
3. No of slots to divide (say 4)

   then time will divide as 11:00:00, 14:00:00, 17:00:00, 20:00:00

So it will calculate the times according to no of slots to divide. If you have any algorithms to calculate it java. And the accuracy will be nearly 15 minutes round figure.
 Please suggest me. Thx in advance

Comment: ok thx.... 1 more help please.. Why there is -ve marks for the question... why ans how to do it??

Comment: If someone think your question is not clear (or) there are lot of similar questions were already asked, they may down vote your question.

Comment: hey this isn't even Android-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the basic algorithm. All times are in **milliseconds**. use `new Date(ling timeInMillis)` constructor to create Date equivalents.

```
long available = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
long eachSlotSize = available / numOfSlots;

long slot1Start = start.getTime();
long slot1End = start.getTime() + eachSlotSize;

long slot2Start = slot1End ;
long slot2End = slot1End  + eachSlotSize;

//rest you can complete
```

Comment: thx and how to reach to the nearest 15 min slot...

Comment: @Rashmi you roundup by adding the difference. 3.20 you round it to 3.15 and 3.25 you round it to 3.30. you take the minutes and do some math using modulo % operator